# Possible areas to look into to see the transaction isolation level settings at .NET application side

Tags: c#, .net

One of our application (using .NET n-tier architecture with SQL Server) we are getting DB access using `Serializable` isolation level from .NET application. We are unable to locate where exactly this is set. We are planning to change it to default `ReadCommitted`. Please let me know the possible areas to look into (we have already checked the `ADO.NET` code in `Data Access Layer` and couldn't see any setting explicitly done for this serializable Isolation level) to find it.

We suspect any config setting which is globally enforcing this setting at `.NET` side and unable to find it. (@ DB level we have the default isolation level [i.e `ReadCommitted`] got set).

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's set when you create a new transaction:

```
var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadComitted);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396